# merging two CSS matrix transforms

Tags: css, css-transforms

so I have an svg file that I have exported from one of my vector editing programs, and due of the way some of the transforms were applied to the exported file, I now have elements in my file with two matrix transforms. i.e. `transform="matrix(1,0,0,1.67,-29,-174.536) matrix(0.898339,0,0,0.537927,30.3643,22.088)"`

I didn't know this was legal syntax until now, so I wanted to get some confirmation on what I think might be the right way to merge them.

given the following transforms: `matrix(1,0,0,1.67,-29,-174.536) matrix(0.902758,0,0,0.540574,125.939,20.9333)`, you would take each of the first matrix transform's parameters, and add that with corresponding parameter of the second matrix transform.

so basically, would `matrix(1,0,0,1.67,-29,-174.536) + matrix(0.902758,0,0,0.540574,125.939,20.9333) = matrix(1.902758,0,0,2.210574,-29,-153.6027)`

Comment: it's not an addition but a multiplication

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thank you!